# How to get the resolution of an image?

Tags: python, image, pygame, resolution

There must be an easy solution for this but I'm just wondering how to get the resolution of an image in Pygame...

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Comment: Did you consult the API documentation of pygame?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size

an image is retrieved as an Surface in pygame, the method `get_size()` will return the tuple `(width,height)`

Answer (score 1):

using this method `get_size()` will return the width and height of the Surface in pixels.
using `get_width()` will return the width of the surface
and `get_height()` will return the height of the surface
http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get_rect()` on image, screen or other surface to have all - `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `centerx`, `centery`, `center`, `bottom`, `right`, `bottomright`, etc. (see: [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect))

```
image = pygame.image.load("some_image")

image_rect = image.get_rect()

print image_rect.x, image_rect.y, image_rect.width, image_rect.height
print image_rect.centerx, image_rect.centery, image_rect.center # etc.

# using rect to center image on screen

image_rect.center = screen.get_rect().center

# using rect to blit image

screen.blit( image, image_rect )
```

If you change `x` or `y` (or others) `rect` automaticly recalculates rest - `centerx`, `centery`, etc. 
(The same way if you change `centerx`, `centery` - `rect` recalculates `x`, `y`)